# How to prevent deleting , editing and dragging records in tree. Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

In Ext.tree.Panel, editing records is done by rowediting plugin.
How to prevent deleting or editing the topmost Root record?

And how to prohibit dragging the top records except childNodes?

Dragging is done using the treeviewdragdrop plugin.
Below is the plugin code.

```
...
plugins: [{
        ptype: 'rowediting',
        clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
        autoCancel: false,
        listeners: {
            afteredit : function (editor, context, eOpts ){
                context.store.reload();

            },
            canceledit : function ( editor, context, eOpts ){
                context.store.reload();

            }
        }
    }],
    viewConfig: {
        plugins: [{
            ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
            containerScroll: true
        }]
    }, 
...
```

Example in [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2nv2) , on file app/view/QuestionTree.js

Comment: By `top records` you mean folders?

Comment: Yes, `top records` it folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For preventing editing you can use [`beforeedit`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing.html#event-beforeedit) event where you can return false and cancel the operation. Same way you can use [`beforedrop`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.tree.plugin.TreeViewDragDrop.html#event-beforedrop) for preventing drop. Here's the [**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2o1u) (in `QuestionTree.js`)

```
beforeedit: function (editor, context) {
    return !context.record.isRoot();
}
```

```
listeners: {
    beforedrop: function (node, data, overModel, dropPosition) {
        return data.records[0].isLeaf();
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the solution, to prevent the drag on topmost records you could also use:

```
       listeners: {
            viewready: function (tree) {
                var view = tree.getView(),
                    dd = view.findPlugin('treeviewdragdrop');

                dd.dragZone.onBeforeDrag = function (data, e) {
                    var rec = view.getRecord(e.getTarget(view.itemSelector));
                    return rec.isLeaf();
                };
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much